# null inesperado en system.out.println

Tags: java

Pidiendo **nombre**, **apellido** y **año de nacimiento** al usuario se genera una clave provisoria, primero se separan las consonantes y las vocales de cada cadena por separado (`nameC` consonante, `lastnC` consonante, `nameV` vocales, `lastnV` vocales) luego se estima una edad restando el año ingresado a 2019.

La clave que genera esta compuesta por las consonantes de la cadena mas larga en mayúscula (nombre o apellido), las vocales en orden inversa de la cadena mas corta, también en mayúsculas y a lo ultimo la edad estimada.

Si ingreso para 
 `name = "Luis"`  `lastname = "Espinoza"` `yearbirth = 1995`

la clave debería ser: **SPNZIU24**

Sin embargo, la salida muestra: **NULLSPNZIUNULL24**

¿Porque aparecen esos NULL?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Key{

    private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String nameC;
    private String nameV;
    private String lastnC;
    private String lastnV;
    private String key;
    private int years;
    private int yearbirth = 0;

    private void registration(){

        System.out.println("Bienvenido a codigoJava, para ingresar necesitaremos unos pocos datos...");
        System.out.println("Porfavor ingresa tu nombre");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Porfavor ingresa tu apellido");
        lastName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Y para terminar aÃ±o de nacimiento");
        while(yearbirth<1900 || yearbirth>2019){
            yearbirth = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public int years(int yearbirth){
        years = 2019 - yearbirth;
        return years;
    }

    private void keyBuilder(){

        for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++){
            if(name.charAt(i) == 'a' || name.charAt(i) == 'e' || name.charAt(i) == 'i' || name.charAt(i) == 'o' || name.charAt(i) == 'u' ){
                nameV = name.charAt(i) + nameV;
            }else{
                nameC = nameC + name.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        for(int o = 0; o < lastName.length() ; o++){
            if(lastName.charAt(o) == 'a' || lastName.charAt(o) == 'e' || lastName.charAt(o) == 'i' || lastName.charAt(o) == 'o' || lastName.charAt(o) == 'u' ){
                lastnV = lastName.charAt(o) + lastnV;
            }else{
                lastnC = lastnC + lastName.charAt(o);
            }
        }

        if(lastnC.length() > nameC.length()){
            key = lastnC.toUpperCase() + nameV.toUpperCase() + years(yearbirth);
            System.out.println(key);
        }else{
            key = nameC.toUpperCase() + lastnV.toUpperCase() + years(yearbirth);
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[]args){

        Key newUser = new Key();
        newUser.registration();
        newUser.keyBuilder();

    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: no estoy muy seguro y por eso no contesto, pero el valor por defecto de un string es NULL... tal vez esta sumando eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en que las variables no las estás inicializando en ningún momento. También he visto que no estás utilizando ningún constructor de la clase, que es donde deberían de inicializarse esas variables, también puedes inicializar la variable  `yearbirth` a `0` en el `constructor`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Key {

    private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String nameC;
    private String nameV;
    private String lastnC;
    private String lastnV;
    private String key;
    private int years;
    private int yearbirth;
    public Key() {
        nameC = "";
        nameV="";
        lastnC = "";
        lastnV = "";
        name = "";
        lastName = "";
        lastnC = "";
        lastnV = "";
        yearbirth=0;

    }

    private void registration() {

        System.out.println("Bienvenido a codigoJava, para ingresar necesitaremos unos pocos datos...");
        System.out.println("Porfavor ingresa tu nombre");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Porfavor ingresa tu apellido");
        lastName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Y para terminar aÃ±o de nacimiento");
        while (yearbirth < 1900 || yearbirth > 2019) {
            yearbirth = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public int years(int yearbirth) {
        years = 2019 - yearbirth;
        return years;
    }

    private void keyBuilder() {

        for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
            if (name.charAt(i) == 'a' || name.charAt(i) == 'e' || name.charAt(i) == 'i' || name.charAt(i) == 'o'
                    || name.charAt(i) == 'u') {
                nameV = name.charAt(i) + nameV;
            } else {
                nameC = nameC + name.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        for (int o = 0; o < lastName.length(); o++) {
            if (lastName.charAt(o) == 'a' || lastName.charAt(o) == 'e' || lastName.charAt(o) == 'i'
                    || lastName.charAt(o) == 'o' || lastName.charAt(o) == 'u') {
                lastnV = lastName.charAt(o) + lastnV;
            } else {
                lastnC = lastnC + lastName.charAt(o);
            }
        }

        if (lastnC.length() > nameC.length()) {
            key = lastnC.toUpperCase() + nameV.toUpperCase() + years(yearbirth);
            System.out.println(key);
        } else {
            key = nameC.toUpperCase() + lastnV.toUpperCase() + years(yearbirth);
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Key newUser = new Key();
        newUser.registration();
        newUser.keyBuilder();

    }
}
```

Comment: Tenias razón, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en que no estas inicializando las variables de `nameC`, `nameV`, `lastnC` y `lastnV` por lo menos con un string vacío, por eso al no estar inicializadas su valor por defecto es `null`, he ahí la razón.

Podrías hacerlo en el método `keyBuilder`, por ejemplo así:

```
private void keyBuilder(){
    nameC = nameV = lastnC = lastnV = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++){
        if(name.charAt(i) == 'a' || name.charAt(i) == 'e' || name.charAt(i) == 'i' || name.charAt(i) == 'o' || name.charAt(i) == 'u' ){
            nameV = name.charAt(i) + nameV;
        }else{
            nameC = nameC + name.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    for(int o = 0; o < lastName.length() ; o++){
        if(lastName.charAt(o) == 'a' || lastName.charAt(o) == 'e' || lastName.charAt(o) == 'i' || lastName.charAt(o) == 'o' || lastName.charAt(o) == 'u' ){
            lastnV = lastName.charAt(o) + lastnV;
        }else{
            lastnC = lastnC + lastName.charAt(o);
        }
    }

    if(lastnC.length() > nameC.length()){
        key = lastnC.toUpperCase() + nameV.toUpperCase() + years(yearbirth);
        System.out.println(key);
    }else{
        key = nameC.toUpperCase() + lastnV.toUpperCase() + years(yearbirth);
        System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```